# Convert four character date string to a date string

Tags: go

I am receiving the expiry date as a four-letter string like this, "1226"
I need to create a date string from that data.

so far I can get the month and year. tried using time.Parse method was mentioned in the docs but I couldn't figure it out.

```
func main() {

    dateData := "1226"
    month := dateData[:2]
    year := dateData[2:]
    t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02", fmt.Sprintf("20%s-%s-00", year, month))
    fmt.Println(t)
    // expected output is "2026-12-01", and also it's better if we could add one month to this one. then it will become "2027-01-01"

}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I am receiving the expiry date as a four-letter string like this, "1226"

---

> expected output is "2026-12-01

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    date := "1226"
    if len(date) == 4 {
        date = date[0:2] + "20" + date[2:4]
    }
    t, err := time.Parse("012006", date)
    fmt.Println(t, err)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/fwfBux1AZQO

```
2026-12-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

---

> it's better if we could add one month to this one. then it will become "2027-01-01"

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    date := "1226"
    if len(date) == 4 {
        date = date[0:2] + "20" + date[2:4]
    }
    t, err := time.Parse("012006", date)
    if err == nil {
        t = t.AddDate(0, 1, 0)
    }
    fmt.Println(t, err)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/xCAyxPdRjib

```
2027-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

Comment: You don't need to prepend the century. This works just as well: https://go.dev/play/p/fDk8K78X03B

Comment: @NunoCruces: Not true. First, read the documentation: "For layouts specifying the two-digit year 06, a value NN >= 69 will be treated as 19NN and a value NN < 69 will be treated as 20NN." Second, consider the Y2K problem. Third, consider an obvious expiration date use case, credit cards. You want to introduce a pernicious bug which takes effect starting in 2069: all credit cards with a two-digit expiration year on or after 69 expire in the 19NN! My solution works for all four-digit expiration years and two-digit expiration years througn 2099.

Answer (score -1):

Does this work for you?

https://go.dev/play/p/hrwVa_CvGYL

```
func DateStringFromTime(t time.Time) string {
    return (strings.Split(fmt.Sprint(t), " "))[0]
}

func TimeFromMMYY(dateData string) (time.Time, error) {

    t := time.Time{}

    if len(dateData) != 4 {
        return t, errors.New("bad date string")
    }

    month := dateData[:2]
    year := dateData[2:]
    m, err := strconv.Atoi(month)
    if err != nil {
        return t, err
    }

    y, err := strconv.Atoi(year)
    if err != nil {
        return t, err
    }

    loc := time.UTC // or time.Local
    t = time.Date(2000+y, time.Month(m), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)

    return t, nil
}
func main() {

    dateData := "1226"

    t, _ := TimeFromMMYY(dateData)

    fmt.Println(DateStringFromTime(t)) // prints 2026-12-01

    // add a month
    t = t.AddDate(0, 1, 0)
    fmt.Println(DateStringFromTime(t)) // prints 2027-01-01
}
```